# Using GUID as id in Symfony, schema validation always fails

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, guid, uuid

I have created entities in Symfony and used `guid` type for `id` instead (check below as an example).

```
/**
 * Activities
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="activities")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Activities
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @var string
    * @ORM\Column(name="Action", type="string", length=255)
    */
   private $activityAction;
}
```

Everything is fine and my project works (even the relationship between existing tables are fine). I can insert, delete, edit data. The only problem is when I validate the schema by `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate` it always fails on sync status with DB level.
When I dump the sql to see what's the changes it just regenerate those ids like:

```
ALTER TABLE activities CHANGE id id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

Does anybody know what is wrong here and how can I fix this?
*I dropped my DB and regenerate the schema, but still it's same (I am using Symfony 2.4)*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is the ID field in your database and can you tell us what database you are using?

Comment: @George In DB it's defined as "varchar(255)", collation = "UTF8-unicode-ci". I use MySQL 5.5.27; Apache version 2.4.3; PHP 5.4.7

Comment: I doubt this is the solution, but you confirmed that the field does not allow null values in the MySql schema?  I think by labeling the field with GeneratedValue, it needs a SequenceGenerator associated because you are relying on the database to create the non sequential ID.  If you are generating the ID within the program with your own method, then I do not think you do not need to put in the GeneratedValue field?  I use PostgreSQL and do not have my experience with MySQL.

Comment: @George Thanks; I guess it depends on DB type and DB version. I tried to build same DB and table structure in a Linux box with Apache 2.2.22; MySQL 5.5.34 and it works fine without those schema validation issues :/